# Monitoring ElasticSearch with Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am new to DevOps side of things for elastic search and have a few questions regarding effective monitoring of a elastic search cluster using Graphana

## What I tried

1. run elasticsearch locally

```
curl http://localhost:9200/

{
  "name" : "hnsKXlb",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "IsSAzHcZTDSA40Lfy0PKcw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "b2f0c09",
    "build_date" : "2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

2. run graphana locally

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 --net network_name \
-e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx" \
grafana/grafana
```

3. added an ElasticSearch datasource

[image: setting up elastic search datasource in graphana]

4. Imported graphana dashboard

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/878

## Question

1. I don't seem to get any metrics
2. I suspect that the datasource is only allowing grafana to that specific index. How can I make it more generic ?

Comment: You need to have Prometheus/Graphite/Logstash/Beats setup which will collect the metrics and store it in Elasticsearch. And then you can visualize the metric data in Grafana.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I wrongly assumed that the dashboard queries the statistics endpoint of elasticsearch and ES itself stores some stats about the environment it is running on. thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into the tools like Prometheus/Graphite/Logstash/Beats which will collect the metrics from Elasticsearch and add it into ES. First, we need to collect the metrics and store it into Elasticsearch. Then we can have a tool like Grafana to visualize the data. Kibana has a built-in dashboard to visualize the cluster health. You can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/elasticsearch-metrics.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an elasticsearch exporter (eexporter) to export metric to prometheus then use prometheus as datasource in Grafana